# Does anybody know how to draw this mesh shape in matlab?

Tags: matlab, mesh

Does anybody know how to draw this mesh shape in matlab?

Tnx in advance

[image]

Comment: "Does anybody know how to draw this mesh shape in matlab?" The answer is undoubtedly "yes" :). Whether you can [construct the question in a suitable manner for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is less clear.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will not be of code writing, but a few points I've seen in the graph.

- The big arch consists of 4 concentric semirings.
- The arch is splitted into 3 decks by the 4 rings.
- In odd-number decks (#1 & 3), look at the lower (inner) floor, and you have 28 nodes.
- In even-number decks (#2), the lower floor has 14 nodes.
- The mesh-like triangles are just straight lines that connects all these nodes.

You can draw this graph in a x-y plot. First draw the rings, with commands like `plot`; then mark the nodes, and connect them by `line`.